# Lucene Search: Associate different words to a term

Tags: search, lucene, associations

I'm using Atlassian Confluence which uses Lucene as searchengine.

I wanna associate a list of words to a specific search term.

Example: The user searches for "DNA", then i want lucene to look in a table if there is field for DNA...next to the DNA stands "DNS" (which is the german term). After this lookup, lucene should search for DNA OR DNS.

Context: Our company is international and the people from the denmark should find the content that is written in german.

I now that we have to set up these index by ourself. Thats okay, there are only some special words that are used, so we can handle the association.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a SynonymFilter in your Analyzer.

Follow the snippets of example to search also for "DNS" every time you search "DNA"

- First of all you must create SynonymMap where you declare the synonyms (DNA--> DNS)

> ```
> SynonymMap.Builder sb = new SynonymMap.Builder ( true );
> sb.add ( new CharsRef("DNA"), new CharsRef("DNS"), true );
> // ...add here others synonyms
> SynonymMap synonymMap = sb.build();
> ```

- Then, you must create a SynonymAnalyzer class. The constructor of this class receives the SynonymMap created previously

> ```
> public class SynonymAnalyzer extends Analyzer {   
>   public static final Version version = Version.LUCENE_47;
>
>   private SynonymMap synonyms;
>
>   public SynonymAnalyzer(SynonymMap synonyms) { 
>    setSynonyms(synonyms);     
>   }
>
>   @Override   protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
>   TokenStreamComponents result = null;
>
>   WhitespaceTokenizer source = new WhitespaceTokenizer(version, reader);
>   SynonymFilter filter = new SynonymFilter(source, getSynonyms(), true);      
>   result = new TokenStreamComponents(source, filter);
>
>   return result;  
>  }
>
> public SynonymMap getSynonyms() {         
>    return synonyms;   
> }
>
>   protected void setSynonyms(SynonymMap synonyms) {
>      this.synonyms = synonyms;
>   }
>
> }
> ```

- Finally, when you search a term "DNA" and you apply SynonymAnalyzer, the query is expanded with synonyms.

  > ```
  >  IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open ( yourIndex );             
  >  IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher ( reader ); 
  >  SynonymAnalyzer analyzer = new SynonymAnalyzer ( synonymMap );
  >
  >
  >   QueryParser query = new QueryParser ( version, "yourDftField", analyzer );
  >   Query queryParsed = query.parse ( "DNA" );
  >   TopDocs topDocs = searcher.search ( queryParsed, 10 );
  > ```